# phpQuery register xml namespace in html?

Tags: php, html, xml, xml-namespaces, phpquery

I'm creating a simple templating system. I know PHP is a great template-system but I don't want clients to add PHP and ruin things. So I'm using phpQuery to parse simple tags in the HTML.

I can create a custom tag like `<bar />` and parse that, but I was wondering if it is necessary to add a namespace like `<foo:bar />`. However just doing `pq('foo:bar')` or `pq('foo|bar')` doesn't find the element as phpQuery seems to strip 'foo:' from the tag. Is there a way to register an xml namespace in html so that phpQuery can parse it?

Comment: Sadly the phpQuery project seems orphaned and their documentation is flooded with malicious scripts which makes it hard to give good reference and advice. I suspect the project is dead and you should consider alternatives like for example [FluentDOM](https://fluentdom.github.io/) which also has a jQuery like interface and which supports xpath you're looking for. Just FYI: xpath queries isn't part of the jQuery notation any longer. So you need to explicitly need to look for xpath support not only jquery-like-selector support.